# Hadoop Sqoop Export to MS-SQL database

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, export, sqoop

The following connection for a sqoop export does not work

```
sqoop export \

                -- connect jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://10.134.777.844/ABC_FB \

                --table ABC_PAYE_TYP \

                --username aUSER \

                --P \

                --m 1 \

                --export-dir /test2/smith/financial/abc/abcdb/pmt_typ/000001_0
```

> ERROR 
>       Export requires a --table or a --call argument

What is wrong with the above
( i thought i provided the table ... hmmm )
do i need schema or something else ?

Comment: Try manually typing the `-` (don't copy from elsewhere)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help... it is appreciated !  It worked

Comment: Okay. I'm voting to close this post as just a typo, then